# How to start and end a loop with user input?

Tags: java, loops

I am having trouble figuring out how to prompt a question that allows for the user to enter a number or character to start or end a loop.

The following is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class diceRoller{
    public static void main(String[] args){     

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int score;
        int sum=0;
        int roll1 = genRanInRange(1, 6);
        int roll2 = genRanInRange(1, 6);
        int roll3 = genRanInRange(1, 6);
        System.out.println("Your rolls were: " + " " + roll1 + " " + roll2 + " " + roll3);      
            if (roll1 == roll2 || roll2 == roll3 || roll1 == roll3){ // start of first loop

                System.out.println("You had 2 matching rolls! You gain 50 points.");
                score = 50;
                sum += score;
                if (roll1 == roll2 && roll2 == roll3 && roll1 == roll3){ // nested loop

                int rollSum = roll1 + roll2 + roll3;
                    if (rollSum == 18){ // nested loop 2

                    System.out.println("You had 3 matching 6's! You gain 500 points.");
                    score = 500;                        
                    sum += score;   
                    } // end nested loop 2

                } // end nested loop

            } // end of first loop

            else { 
                System.out.println("Sorry, you had 0 matching die.");
                score = 1;
                sum -= score;
            }
                System.out.println("Your score was: " + sum);   

            if (sum > 0){
                System.out.println("Would you like to continue?");
                }

            else{

                System.out.println("You are out of points. Would you like to restart?");
                }

    } // end Main

    public static int genRanInRange(int start, int end)
    {
        return (int)(Math.random()*(end-start+1.0)) + start;
    } // end genRanInRange

} // end Dice Roller
```

Comment: An `if` condition is not a loop. It's a branch. As a matter of fact, your code doesn't contain any loop at all.

Comment: What do you want the user to input from keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
System.out.print("Would you like to continue? Y/N: ");
String UserResp = scanner.nextLine();
```

Put the rest of the code in a while loop.
and have there be a boolean defined at the beginning as true for the first loop, and then compare UserResp to Y or N to set the boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceRoller{
    public static void main(String[] args){     

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int score;
        int sum=0;
        char ans='y'; 
        while(ans=='Y'||ans=='y'){ //loop while user says Y 
            int roll1 = genRanInRange(1, 6);
            int roll2 = genRanInRange(1, 6);
            int roll3 = genRanInRange(1, 6);
            System.out.println("Your rolls were: " + " " + roll1 + " " + roll2 + " " + roll3);      
            if (roll1 == roll2 || roll2 == roll3 || roll1 == roll3){ // start of first loop
                System.out.println("You had 2 matching rolls! You gain 50 points.");
                score = 50;
                sum += score;
                if (roll1 == roll2 && roll2 == roll3 && roll1 == roll3){ // nested loop
                int rollSum = roll1 + roll2 + roll3;
                    if (rollSum == 18){ // nested loop 2

                    System.out.println("You had 3 matching 6's! You gain 500 points.");
                    score = 500;                        
                    sum += score;   
                    } // end nested loop 2

                } // end nested loop

            } // end of first loop

            else { 
                System.out.println("Sorry, you had 0 matching die.");
                score = 1;
                sum -= score;
            }
                System.out.println("Your score was: " + sum);   

            if (sum > 0){
                System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(Y/N) ");
                    ans=keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                }
            else{
                System.out.println("You are out of points. Would you like to restart?(Y/N) ");
                ans=keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            }

        }
        keyboard.close(); //Don't forget to close sccaner. 
    } // end Main

    public static int genRanInRange(int start, int end)
    {
        return (int)(Math.random()*(end-start+1.0)) + start;
    } // end genRanInRange

} // end Dice Roller
```

I changed the capitalization of your class from **diceRoller** to **DiceRoller.**

> Class names should always have it's first letter **CAPITALIZED**'

One more thing:

> Don't forget to close the scanner.